# Spring Data-MongoDb Options for aggregation method

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

How can i set "***allowDiskUse***" option in aggregation method in spring data-mongodb framework ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core aggregation abstraction in Spring Data MongoDB is - as the name suggests - `Aggregation`. It exposes a fluent API to build up a pipeline using aggregation operations.

As of version 1.6.0.M1 the `Aggregation` class has a `….withOptions(…)` [method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.6.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#withOptions(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOptions)) to be used like this:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(…) // build up pipeline in here
  .withOptions(newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());
```

Comment: Thanx Oliver,well what about version 1.3.2 ? and what about in version 1.5.2 ?

Comment: They don't have that feature, that's why I explicitly named 1.6 M1.

Comment: I did the same but still getting the same error. do i need to configure something else? Using  mongo version 3.4

Comment: Solutions works! Previously i was doing aggregation.withOptions( options ) separately and it ignored my custom configuration;

Answer (score -2):

I found spring data-mongodb to have limited support for the aggregation framework, however you can simply use the native library leveraging spring mongo template:

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("myCollection").aggregate(pipeline)
```

See 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/com/mongodb/AggregationTest.java 
on how to setup the `List<DBObject> pipeline` and how to setup `allowDiskUse` to true using the `AggregationOptions`.

Comment: I was not being negative, I didn't know in version 1.6.0 (which is not in GA) there was a support for that nor there is anything in the documentation. I am glad more support is coming for the Aggregation framework. I do use Spring MongoDB quite a lot and in general I am very happy with it.