# MongoDB: How can I optimize the aggregation query with big data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

In the Mongodb collection, There are 30 million records. When query with exist values it given result within 1 second. But query with not exist value it taken 40 or 45 seconds to give result as null or 0. Why is it happened like that

```
String cDate = dateFormat.format(date);
String pastTime = timeFormatMin.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000));
Criteria dateQuery = Criteria.where("Date").is(cDate);
Criteria timeQuery = Criteria.where("Time").gt(pastTime);
Criteria appQuery = Criteria.where("appID").is(appId).andOperator(Criteria.where("appID").exists(true));
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(dateQuery, timeQuery, appQuery);

MatchOperation matchOperation = match(criteria);
GroupOperation groupOperation = group("appID").count().as("idcount");
ProjectionOperation projection = project()
            .andExpression("_id").as("appID")
            .andExpression("idcount").as("Count");
SortOperation sortOperation = sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));
LimitOperation limitOperation = limit(1);

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, sortOperation, limitOperation);
AggregationResults<CommonLogic> logResult = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "commonLogic", CommonLogic.class);
List<CommonLogic> list = logResult.getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that field 'appID' is already indexed in DB (which helps the aggregation pipeline a lot):
For the data size mentioned, the above query is most likely to consume time in sort operation. try giving the aggregation option of 'allowDiskUse:true'. Have a look at
[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224088/spring-data-mongodb-options-for-aggregation-method)

Comment: Thanks for your support.
Yes.field 'appID' is already indexed in DB.
Ok, I will check...